# What is the origin of the name of the street Kings Butts in London, and its lack of apostrophes?

Tags: united-kingdom, london, english-language

[image]

I’m mainly interested in why there are no apostrophes in this name. If Butts refers to archery, then why not “King’s Butts” or “Kings’ Butts”? Are apostrophes commonly omitted in historical London street names? Or does Kings refer to an area and “Kings” is acting as an adjective?

Comment: Could you edit your question to clarify what you've looked into already, complete with links and references, and context if applicable? In particular, please let us know what you find missing or unclear about the Wikipedia entry on the topic, if one exists. This allows those who might want to answer to do so without needing to redo the work you've already done. You might find it helpful to review the site tour and Help Centre and, in particular, How to Ask. See also: https://londontopia.net/culture/amusing-london-street-names/

Comment: London is inconsistent with the use of [apostrophes in place names](https://londonist.com/2015/07/itsnotpossibletogetanapostropheinaurl) but modern street signage usually omits them. In the case of Kings Butts, the nearby Archery Road, Strongbow Road and Strongbow Crescent suggest that a town-planner had a bit of a theme going so it's not necessarily a historic name.

Comment: Near me is St Pauls in Bristol. You see St Pauls and St Paul's on official notices and signs of differing ages, and in official documents.

Comment: A 'butts' was a field used for practising archery. In that location in Eltham, there used to be a large royal palace, Eltham Palace, built for Edward IV and later occupied by the young Henry VIII. There are other streets with palace-related names in that vicinity.